# how to rename a system group like `staff`

Tags: user-account, group

I was not able to rename an existing system group via `/etc/group` nor via the tool `dscl`.

Is it even possible to rename a group?

Would it be better to delete and re-create the group with the same GID as before?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Renaming of groups is non that uncommon, at least on Linux I'm used to doing that.

Comment: Again why? My user has been part of staff for nearly 30 years. Also what are the exact commands you tried.

Comment: Renaming the built-in groups that parts of the OS may assume are there? Sounds like a recipe for trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On modern macOS the system volume is read-only, signed and sealed in order to preserve integrity. You can disable that protection, and then you'll be able to rename the staff group as you like. However, I do not see any point whatsoever in doing so.